# Run a ASP.NET application with mono

Tags: asp.net, linux, web, mono

I will run an asp.net application on a linux system with mono.
The application run on the iis without problems.
I published the application with VS to the IIS.
I put the same content to my linux machine.

The file structure looks like this for the IIS:

[image]

How can I start this application on a linux machine with mono?

Comment: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/porting-aspnet-applications/

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you are wanting to do. You could use Mono XSP4, which is a web server distributed with mono (primary use is for debug and therefore has limitations but it will run your site).

You can find installation instructions on the mono project web site (http://www.monodevelop.com/download/linux/). The package on ubuntu is called mono-xsp4 but you will need to add the mono project repos.

Once installed running it is simple:

$ cd /path/to/your/aspnet/project/root
$ xsp4

This will fire it up and run it on the default port with an option to kill it from the command line by hitting enter.

A few options to help:

$ xsp4 --nonstop --port=443 --https --cert=/my/cert.crt --pkfile=/my/key --pkpwd=mykeypwd

Non stop means the server will run without ability to stop using enter. Port is self-explanatory. The rest of the options are about running with HTTPS should you want to do that.

Hope this helps. Happy coding.